# Use babel grammar syntax highlighting in atom for typescript files

Tags: typescript, ide, grammar, atom-editor, babeljs

I have 2 packages installed for atom

`atom-typescript` and `language-babel`, second one has better syntax highlighting features for es6 syntax in my opinion and I want to use it for `.ts` files (typescript) instead of grammar syntax provided by `atom-typescript` package.

I can do this manually for each file in atom by selecting this option from bar on the right bottom cornet, but can't find a way to config this so it is applied to every file in the future.